# Mongo _id for subdocument array

Tags: mongodb

I wish to add an _id as property for objects in a mongo array.

Is this good practice ? 
Are there any problems with indexing ?

Comment: The question is a little vague as it is. Can you give a little more details?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245538/mongodb-id-cannot-be-an-array

Comment: I don't think that link has anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 23):

> I wish to add an _id as property for objects in a mongo array.

I assume:

```
{
    g: [
        { _id: ObjectId(), property: '' },
        // next
    ]
}
```

Type of structure for this question.

> Is this good practice ?

Not normally. `_id`s are unique identifiers for entities. As such if you are looking to add `_id` within a sub-document object then you might not have normalised your data very well and it could be a sign of a fundamental flaw within your schema design.

Sub-documents are designed to contain repeating data for that document, i.e. the addresses or a user or something.

That being said `_id` is not always a bad thing to add. Take the example I just stated with addresses. Imagine you were to have a shopping cart system and (for some reason) you didn't replicate the address to the order document then you would use an `_id` or some other identifier to get that sub-document out.

Also you have to take into consideration linking documents. If that `_id` describes another document and the properties are custom attributes for that document in relation to that linked document then that's okay too.

> Are there any problems with indexing ?

An `ObjectId` is still quite sizeable so that is something to take into consideration over a smaller, less unique id or not using an `_id` at all for sub-documents.

For indexes it doesn't really work any different to the standard `_id` field on the document itself and a unique index across the field should work across the collection (scenario dependant, test your queries).

NB: MongoDB will not add an `_id` to sub-documents for you.

Comment: @aioobe I think in this case yes I meant normalisation, it is a very old answer but I believe I meant about him not separating entities very well which would be normalisation.

Comment: If I create a mongodb object _id on a sub document, is that _id automatically unique across entire collection?

Comment: In 90% of cases, yes, but time fragments can conflict however, MongoDB did something to fix that some time ago

Comment: 90% is *really* scary.. :s

Comment: I'd like to add that Mongoose, on the other side, *will* automatically add a `_id` for each sub-document.