# Mongoose how to auto add _id to objects in array within collection item?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a mongo collection that looks like this:

```
{
    name: string
    _id: (auto set)
    items: array[
        name: string
        url: string
        items: array[
            {
                name: string,
                url: string,
                items: []
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I'm using `findByIdAndUpdate` (with mongoose) to add an item into the items array:

```
Menu.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.body.parentid, 
    {
        $push: {
            items: {
                name: req.body.item.name, 
                url: req.body.item.url,
                items: []
            }
        }
    },
    {
        safe: true, 
        upsert: true, 
        new: true
    },
    function(err, model) {
        if (err !== null) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
);
```

This works fine, but it does not add an `_id` to each object inserted into the `items` array. And i really need an id for each one.

I'm guessing it comes from the method used, `findByIdAndUpdate` as it looks more like an update rather than an insert. If my thinking is correct.

Using mongodb 3.2.10 and mongoose 4.7.6.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT: the `_id: (auto set)` is not real, it's being automatically added via mongo. But just at the top level objects.

Comment: What happens if you set the `setDefaultsOnInsert` option to `true`?

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution in this thread: [mongoDB : Creating An ObjectId For Each New Child Added To The Array Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050750/mongodb-creating-an-objectid-for-each-new-child-added-to-the-array-field)

basically, added

`var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`

and then forcing the creation:

```
$push: {
    items: {
        _id: new ObjectID(),
        name: req.body.item.name, 
        url: req.body.item.url,
        items: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to sepcify _id: (auto set) in mongoose schema it will automatically add unique _id with each document.

Comment: What i thought, but, when i check via the mongo shell, i do not see any `_id` being added. Just for the top level objects where i wrote `_id: (auto set)`.

Comment: One other way of doing it
_id:    {type:ObjectIdSchema, default: function () { return new ObjectId()} }

Comment: Check in some other GUI like RoboMongo. There should be a unique id in the document it can be Auto Generated ObjectId with key '_id'

Comment: Yes i've checked with robomongo and there is really none. Check this screenshot: https://s27.postimg.org/iw7zftr6b/Screen_Shot_2017_01_16_at_15_12_19.png
I'm gonna try your second comment.

Comment: ObjectId('587cd...') is the unique id generated with your document

Comment: Agreed. That one works fine. But my objects in the array item need one as well.

Comment: Ok i got your point you need unique ObjectIds in each Object in Items Array 
try this schema
 items: [{
   name: string
   url: string
   items: [
    {
     name: string,
     url: string,
     items: []
    }
   ]
   }
  ]

Comment: Found the solution thanks to your help and this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050750/mongodb-creating-an-objectid-for-each-new-child-added-to-the-array-field
Thanks for the help!

Comment: As a follow up of @kevin's comment, if you are using mongoose, do NOT put _id explicitly in the doc type array elements and specify a default value, because this will assign the same _id to all the doc elements in the array. Just specify the fields other than _id.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't define _id in Schema, mongoose automatically add a _id to array item.
for example:

```
const countrySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  cities: [
    {
      // don't define _id here.
      name: String
    }
  ],
});
```

now when you insert a row, the result is something like this:

> {name : 'Iran', cities : [{_id : 6202902b45f0d858ac141537,name :
> 'Tabriz'}]}