# How to generate different ObjectId's with MongoDB's positional operator $[]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update every element in the array `days` (I got 7 days, here I only show 3) with the MongoDB positional operator `$[]`. The update correctly pushes an object into every single element of the array `meals`. However, their Object Id's are the same, and I would like them to be different since I will be mapping them. Any ideas?

```
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5db749cf657e1b1e0c3d241c"
    },
    "finished": false,
    "days": [
        {
            "dayName": "Monday",
            "meals": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5dba1cde12f2b650e4b4f89d"
                    },
                    "mealName": "Breakfast",
                    "recipes": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "dayName": "Tuesday",
            "meals": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5dba1cde12f2b650e4b4f89d"
                    },
                    "mealName": "Breakfast",
                    "recipes": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "dayName": "Wednesday",
            "meals": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5dba1cde12f2b650e4b4f89d"
                    },
                    "mealName": "Breakfast",
                    "recipes": []
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can try using [Update Elements By Their Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html), since there are only 7 elements in the array (fixed size). Also, you can share the code you had tried. Note that `$[]` is used to update _all_ elements in the array (with something).

Comment: Or, you can try updating array elements by index using this method: [set elements in array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html#set-elements-in-arrays). Note this is different from using the `$` array update operator.

Comment: I think you have to create 7 `ObjectId`s and update each one at its index position using one of the array update techniques.

Comment: @prasad_ thanks for your answer, apparently there's not a known (according to my research) way to do it with ```$[]```, so I ended up performing a classic for loop, which gave me unique $oids: 

```for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        pushObject[`days.${i}.meals`] = {...otherProperties}
      }```

Comment: There are some posts online with similar subject, and you have to do some searching for more ideas. Here is one of them: [Creating ObjectId For Each New Child Added To The Array Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050750/mongodb-creating-an-objectid-for-each-new-child-added-to-the-array-field)

Comment: What is the reason you are using "$oid" for`_id` value? What is [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html) and ["$oid"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/index.html#bson.ObjectId).