# How to find a particular sub-document in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

This thread states that it is not a very good idea to create `_id` in a sub-document of MongoDB.
[Mongo _id for subdocument array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472589/mongo-id-for-subdocument-array)

I have locations and their reviews in a collection:

So, what would be the way to find a unique sub-document?
What can be set as a primary key for `review` sub-document?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var openingClosingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
                             {
                                  days:    {type: String, required: true},
                                  opening: String,
                                  closing: String,
                                  closed:  {type: String, required: true}
                             }
                        )

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
                    {
                       author:  String,
                       rating:  {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
                       reviewText:  String,
                       createdOn:   {type: Date, default: Date.now}
                    }
                      )


var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
                       {
                        // 'required' keyword is for validation.
                        name:       {type: String, required: true},
                        address:    String,

                        // 'default' keyword can be with or without quotes.
                        // When defining multiple properties for a field, {} are required.
                        rating:     {type: Number, default: 0, min: 0, max: 5},
                        facilities:     [String],

                        // Nest 'openingClosingTimeSchema' under 'locationSchema'.
                        openingTimes:   [openingClosingTimeSchema],

                        // Nest 'reviewSchema' under 'locationSchema'.
                        reviews:    [reviewSchema]
                       }
                    )
```

Comment: It was too old question and answer and i don't think it is bad idea, you can use _id as a primary key,

Answer (score 0):

> it is not a very good idea to create _id in a sub-document of MongoDB

This is not a universally applicable guideline.

If you need to identify subdocuments in an array, an _id field would be helpful (or any other field that would serve the same function).

If you don't need to identify subdocuments, you don't need an identification field.

Since you are in the first category it's perfectly ok to have an _id field in your use case.